# dpkg broken by oracle-java8-installer

Tags: apt, java, dpkg, oracle

I want to remove the oracle-java8-installer but it gives the below errors. Perhaps good to mention that I messed a bit with apt, e.g. at some point I manually removed the apt cache (but the java problem existed already and I do not think it has gotten worse).

```
~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  oracle-java8-installer*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 25 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 129 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 693990 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing oracle-java8-installer (8u45+8u33arm-1~webupd8~1) ...
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javafxpackager (part of link group javafxpackager) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: error: unable to read link `/etc/alternatives/javafxpackager': Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
Installing from local file /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
Removing outdated cached downloads...
mv: cannot move ‘jdk1.8.0_45’ to ‘java-8-oracle/jdk1.8.0_45’: Directory not empty
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here are the last lines of my dpkg log:

```
2015-07-28 22:14:14 startup packages purge
2015-07-28 22:14:14 status half-configured oracle-java8-installer:all 8u45+8u33arm-1~webupd8~1
2015-07-28 22:14:15 remove oracle-java8-installer:all 8u45+8u33arm-1~webupd8~1 <none>
2015-07-28 22:14:15 status half-configured oracle-java8-installer:all 8u45+8u33arm-1~webupd8~1
```

How can I get Java working again?

Answer (score 1):

That repository is not updated. You can install Oracle java 8u51 by a [script](https://github.com/hanipouspilot/oracle-java8) now.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/hanipouspilot/oracle-java8.git
cd oracle-java8
sudo chmod +x javains
sudo ./javains
```

I hope they will update the ppa soon, and I will not have to maintain java installation for good.

Comment: You can follow the steps detailed here: https://askubuntu.com/a/966347 which will allow you to install using the PPA. Its not as automated as one would like, but you do get the benefits of using their package.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the folder

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jdk1.8.0_45
```

Still more you can not break. **;)**

Now purge it again

```
sudo apt-get purge java-oracle8-installer
```

After that, install it again via the outdated PPA or the script in @Pilot6 answer.

Comment: I am afraid the outdated ppa will not install, since it will not be able to download. My script does not need that deb. It should work, if I did not make a stupid mistake in the last revision.

Comment: @Pilot6 is the PPA dead?

Comment: I do not know what happened to maintainers.  Maybe something serious.