# 403: Forbidden error when trying to install oracle-java8-installer

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, oracle

I have a problem while trying to install third-party component Oracle Java 8. Every time I type:

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

I get this answer:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version (8u131-1~webupd8~2).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  snap-confine
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u131-1~webupd8~2) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2017-07-05 15:57:12--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 2.22.144.107, 2.22.144.51
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.22.144.107|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-07-05 15:57:12 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I think I couldn't install Oracle JDK 8. I tried so hard to do this, but I got this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the fact that the PPA maintainer hasn't updated their scripts yet and older updates of Java 8 are no longer available from Oracle.

To quickly resolve this, you can do the following and install 8u151. **(This will only work so long as 8u151 is available from Oracle)**

1) Install as normal:

```
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo 
debconf-set-selections
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
```

Once that is done and you get the error:

```
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

oracle-java8-installer
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

2) You will then have to do the following for 8u151 to be installed:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="e8a341ce566f32c3d06f6d0f0eeea9a0f434f538d22af949ae58bc86f2eeaae4"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="c78200ce409367b296ec39be4427f020e2c585470c4eed01021feada576f027f"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u144|JAVA_VERSION=8u151|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_144|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_151|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/$FILENAME|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/$FILENAME|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

3) Once you complete the above, you can run the install again and it will succeed.

```
sudo apt install -y oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this `403:Forbidden` error:

```
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 2.22.144.107, 2.22.144.51
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.22.144.107|:80... connected. 
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden  
2017-07-05 15:57:12 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

because the Oracle Java 8 installer requires you to accept the Oracle license before the installation begins. You can run the following command to automatically accept the Oracle license:

```
echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
```

Alternatively you can download the JDK tar.gz archive manually from [Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and place it under `/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer` then installing the *oracle-java8-installer* package will use the local archive instead of trying it to download it itself.